# Is there a way to set a condition on the SQL code below? I only want to show up until the end year but am showing the start year + 5 years right now

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Goodmorning everyone I have this SQL code that I am using in Access to show a table of total hours per year on a form. The user has the OPTION of choosing up to 6 years which means they could also simply choose 1 2 3 4 or 5 years. I only want to show the years up to the end year not the full 6 if 6 aren't selected. The way I have the sql written right now takes the start year and adds 1 to it until it reaches year 6 and displays them all. I have a variable for the end year as well and was thinking if there is a way to put in IF startyear + number is greater than endyear then end but not sure how to achieve that. Any help would be super helpful

code:

```
SELECT 
[qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear].EstimateID,
[qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear].FY, 
[qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear].YearID, 
[qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear].SumOfLaborHours 
FROM qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear 
WHERE (((qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear.EstimateID)=Forms!frm_Home.Form.cboEstimate.Value)) 
And (((qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear.YearID)=Forms!frm_Home.Form.cboStartYear.Value)) 
Or (((qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear.EstimateID)=Forms!frm_Home.Form.cboEstimate.Value)) 
And (((qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear.YearID)=Forms!frm_Home.Form.cboStartYear.Value+1)) 
Or (((qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear.EstimateID)=Forms!frm_Home.Form.cboEstimate.Value)) 
And (((qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear.YearID)=Forms!frm_Home.Form.cboStartYear.Value+2)) 
Or (((qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear.EstimateID)=Forms!frm_Home.Form.cboEstimate.Value)) 
And (((qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear.YearID)=Forms!frm_Home.Form.cboStartYear.Value+3)) 
Or (((qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear.EstimateID)=Forms!frm_Home.Form.cboEstimate.Value)) 
And (((qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear.YearID)=Forms!frm_Home.Form.cboStartYear.Value+4)) 
Or (((qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear.EstimateID)=Forms!frm_Home.Form.cboEstimate.Value)) 
And (((qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear.YearID)=Forms!frm_Home.Form.cboStartYear.Value+5)) 
ORDER BY [qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear].EstimateID,
[qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear].FY, 
[qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear].YearID, 
[qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear].SumOfLaborHours;
```

Comment: Just filter using a `WHERE` clause based on `YearID` or whatever data contains that date/year detail.  If you can provide more detail about the structure: columns, types and data contents, that might be helpful.

Comment: Couldn't you express this logic like: `qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear.YearID BETWEEN x AND x+n` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    [qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear].EstimateID,
    [qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear].FY, 
    [qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear].YearID, 
    [qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear].SumOfLaborHours 
FROM 
    qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear 
WHERE 
    qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear.EstimateID = Forms!frm_Home!cboEstimate.Value
    AND
    (qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear.YearID Between 
        Forms!frm_Home!cboStartYear.Value And 
        Forms!frm_Home!cboStartYear.Value + Forms!frm_Home!YearsToSelect.Value)  
ORDER BY 
    [qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear].EstimateID,
    [qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear].FY, 
    [qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear].YearID, 
    [qry_LaborLineItems_TotalLaborHoursPerEstimatePerYear].SumOfLaborHours;
```

where `Forms!frm_Home!YearsToSelect.Value` holds the user's choice of count of years.

Comment: This worked! Thanks for providing such an easy and quick solution